# How to interact javascript onClick event on uiwebview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

UIWebView has camera icon when I click on it, I want show the all images inside `window.JSInterface.slideshow()`. But how can I enable an `onClick` event on `UIWebView` (Here over class has `onClick` camera icon)

Below string that I am getting from service.

```
<style>
.rslides img 
{
 display: block; max-width: 98%; margin: 0 auto; min-height:160px; min-width:320px; background-image: url("http://apps.xxxxx.com/interface/api/assets/placeholder.png"); background-repeat:no-repeat;
 } 
.over
{
background-image: url("http://apps.xxxxxx.com/interface/api/assets/camera.png"); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:48px; height:48px; position: relative; left:20%; top:-50px; z-index:51;
}
</style>

<div class="rslides" onclick="window.JSInterface.slideshow('6383232',
 'http://xxxxx.xxxxx.com/multimedia/dynamic/02094/Nanbenda_Movie_Sti_2094062g.jpg,
http://xxxx.xxxxx.com/multimedia/dynamic/02094/Nanbenda_Movie_Sti_2094061g.jpg,
http://xxxx.xxxxx.com/multimedia/dynamic/02094/Nanbenda_Movie_Sti_2094060g.jpg,
http://xxxx.xxxxx.com/multimedia/dynamic/02094/Nanbenda_Movie_Sti_2094059g.jpg,
http://xxxx.xxxxx.com/multimedia/dynamic/02094/Nanbenda_Movie_Sti_2094057g.jpg,
http://xxxx.xxxxx.com/multimedia/dynamic/02094/Nanbenda_Movie_Sti_2094058g.jpg');">
<img src="http://xxxx.xxxxx.com/multimedia/dynamic/02094/Nanbenda_Movie_Sti_2094062g.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="over" onclick="window.JSInterface.slideshow('6383232', 
'http://xxxx.xxxxx.com/multimedia/dynamic/02094/Nanbenda_Movie_Sti_2094062g.jpg,
http://xxxx.xxxxx.com/multimedia/dynamic/02094/Nanbenda_Movie_Sti_2094061g.jpg,
http://xxxx.xxxxx.com/multimedia/dynamic/02094/Nanbenda_Movie_Sti_2094060g.jpg,
http://xxxx.xxxxx.com/multimedia/dynamic/02094/Nanbenda_Movie_Sti_2094059g.jpg,
http://xxxx.xxxxx.com/multimedia/dynamic/02094/Nanbenda_Movie_Sti_2094057g.jpg,
http://xxxx.xxxxx.com/multimedia/dynamic/02094/Nanbenda_Movie_Sti_2094058g.jpg');">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. fire a URL in your JS onclick function
2. interrupt the URL call in UIWebView's delegate method
   `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`